# How to join two tables and add a column that will link the two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a task where in I have to create two virtual tables and add a column that will link those two virtual tables together. I understand that I can use join statements to join the two virtual tables together, but the only problem is that how can I add a column where in I can link those two tables together using a primary key?

Comment: Just google `JOIN in sql-server`

Comment: In your example none of the Record ID match, is that the real case?  Please elaborate on "add a column that associate the Staff table with the Company table" to clarify your desire.  You want to add a column? to which table?

Comment: to clarify, i want to create a table that has a column that associate the records of both the Company Table and the Staff Table..

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need another table because 1 person can work in many companies and 1 company have many employees. Therefore add another table CompanyStaff for example that will hold companyID an personID then make a join.

CompanyStaff TABLE

ID CompanyID StaffID

```
SELECT * FROM Company c INNER JOIN CompanyStaff cs 
ON c.ID = cs.CompanyID 
INNER JOIN Staff s ON s.ID = cs.StaffID
```

After you can filter or select whatever you want.

You can also add column to Staff table that holds CompanyID but that will be redundant. 
In your example there is no information that links Staff and Company right now, so you cannot make a proper query.

If in those two tables are split record information, you can join them 1-1 on RecordID but those records must be the same in both tables.

Comment: Perhaps, not a very clear question though not your fault :)

Answer (score -1):

you should be pass company id column in staff table(add new column). basis on this you will join tables.